# Trying to create a archive tester for rar and 7z in perl

Tags: perl, archive

i'm trying to create a archive tester for a directory for rar and 7z in perl, my 7z can't handle rar and i can't install the rar function for 7z.

I borrowed a PERL script and adjusted it for rar usage

```
$unrar = "unrar";  #path to 7z.exe from 7-zip program, make sure to use \\ and not single \ in path
$filetypes_rar = "rar";  #filetypes to test, use | between types
$skipdir = "System Volume Information|$RECYCLE.BIN|corrupt";   #don't scan these directories, use | between names

open (OUT, ">>!corrupt.txt");
listdir(".");
printf ("%-79s\n", " ");
print "\n--- Done ---\n";
sleep(600);
close (OUT);
exit;

sub listdir{
    my ($dir) = @_;
    my ($file, @files, @list);
    opendir(DIR, $dir) || return;
    @files = grep { /^[^.]/} readdir(DIR);
    closedir DIR;

    foreach $file(sort(@files)) {
        if (-d "$dir\\$file") {
            if (! ($file =~/^$skipdir$/i)) {
                listdir("$dir\\$file");
            }
        } elsif ($file =~ /\.($filetypes_rar)$/i) {
            open (DATA, "\"$unrar\" t \"$dir\\$file\"|");
            @list = <DATA>;
            close(DATA);
            $info = $list[$#list-1];
            if ($info =~ /Sub items Errors: (\d+)/) {
                if ($1 == 1) {
                    printf ("%-79s\n", substr($file,0,70).": $1 Error");
                } else {
                    printf ("%-79s\n", substr($file,0,69).": $1 Errors");
                }
                print OUT "$dir\\$file\t$1\n";
                if(not (-e "corrupt\\$file")) {
                    rename  ("$dir\\$file", "corrupt\\$file");
                }
            } else {
                printf ("%-79s\r", substr($file,0,75).": OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the following output for a corrupt archive and a correct working archive

```
Cannot open .\corrupttestcase.rar
No such file or directorycorrupttestcase.rar: OK
Cannot open .\ok_file.rar
```

Sorry i really need this to work but my perl knowledge is zero

Comment: What output would you expect? Also, it's better to ask one simple question per post, asking complex things makes it hard for us to help you.

Comment: removed the second part for adding text

Comment: Why do you output `\r` after OK, but not `\n`?

Comment: appologies for my ignorance but after the only ok i can't seen neither \r or \n -   printf ("%-79s\r", substr($file,0,75).": OK");

Comment: The second argument of [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) is formatted by its first argument which contains `\r`.